# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column _____ does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-users

There are a lot of similar posts to this but none that I have found seem to resolve the program. I have tried to add a field to a custom user model that inherits from Django's AbstractUser:

```
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    credibility_rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

When I save this and try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column api_appuser.credibility_rating does not exist
LINE 1: ...ppuser"."is_active", "api_appuser"."date_joined", "api_appus...
```

When I replace the field `credibility_rating` with `pass` the error goes away. Similarly, when I try to add a new field in a different model, the error doesn't occur either. I am not sure if this matters, but I am using Postgres. My `settings.py` file does include `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "api.AppUser"` where api is the name of my app. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Thank you for any help.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column api_appuser.credibility_rating does not exist
LINE 1: ...ppuser"."is_active", "api_appuser"."date_joined", "api_appus...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/Desktop/senior_project/senior_project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/Desktop/senior_project/senior_project/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 455, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/Desktop/senior_project/senior_project/senior_project/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/Desktop/senior_project/senior_project/api/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/Desktop/senior_project/senior_project/api/views.py", line 21, in <module>
    for user in AppUser.objects.all():
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 320, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column api_appuser.credibility_rating does not exist
LINE 1: ...ppuser"."is_active", "api_appuser"."date_joined", "api_appus...
```

Comment: Looks like you execute a query at the module level in `senior_project/api/views.py`, you should never execute queries before your app is loaded- (`for user in AppUser.objects.all():`) what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @IainShelvington I use this to generate a token for each user (I am using Django Rest Framework and Token Authentication to sign users in in a native app). Is there a better place to put this query?

Comment: Put it somewhere it won't be executed simply by importing `views.py`.  Inside a function is a good choice.

Comment: You generate new tokens for every user everytime your app starts? Surely they should be generated at registration time or some other explicit mechanism?

Comment: @IainShelvington I guess so. I am fairly new to this. Is a better way to do it?

Comment: @kmcclenn your error is executing a query at the module level in views.py, remove the query and problem solved. Without knowing why you are doing what you're doing not sure anyone can tell you the best way